# Diameter of a compact in a metric space : is it reached?

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

**Context :**

In a metric space $(E,d)$, we define the diameter of a compact party $K$ as being $\delta =\sup \{d(x,y); x\in K, y\in K\}$.

**Question :**
Is this $\sup$ a $\max$, since $K$ is compact?

I think yes.

**My proof :**

$\delta =\sup \{d(x,y); x\in K, y\in K\}$ so there exists two sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ of elements of $K$ such that $d(x_n,y_n) \rightarrow \delta$.

As elements are in $K$ which is compact, we can extract $(u_{\varphi(n)})$ from $(u_n)$ which converges to $x\in K$. And as $(y_{\varphi(n)})$ is a sequence of elements of $K$, we can extract $(y_{\varphi(\psi(n))})$ which converges to $y\in K$. So $(x_{\varphi(\psi(n))})$ also converges to $x\in K$.

By continuity of the distance, we get that $d(x_{\varphi(\psi(n))}, y_{\varphi(\psi(n))}) \rightarrow d(x,y)$. By unicity of the limit, we have that $\delta = d(x,y)$.

But I'm not sure of what I've done.

Is is right?

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Looks good! At which step were you having a doubt?

Comment: where I use the continuity of $d$ : can I do so even though there are two variables?

Comment: Yes for sure. $(x,y) \mapsto d(x,y)$ is continuous as a map of two variables. You just need to endow $E \times E$ with the appropriate distance, i.e. $d(x_1,x_2) + d(y_1,y_2)$.

Comment: OK. Is there a way to prove it more quickly?

Comment: I would do what I wrote in the answer. It depends on your knowledge on topology though. Do you know that a product of compact is compact? And that a continuous map on a compact attains its extreme values?

Answer (score 1):

The map

$$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
d : & E \times E & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R \\
    & (x,y) & \longmapsto & d(x,y) \end{array}$$

is continuous when $E \times E$ is endowed with the distance
$$D((x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)) = d(x_1,x_2) + d(y_1,y_2).$$

$K \times K$ is compact as it is the product of two compact subsets of $E$. Therefore $f$ attains its supremum on $K \times K$, which proves the desired result.